# Is this a valid jquery conditional statement?

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

```
 if (tag == 'td' && $(this).hasClass('status')) {
        // I am clearing everything inside the td with class status
        $(this).html('')
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to clear... Any suggestion...

I am customizing a form plugin,

```
$.fn.clearForm = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tag == 'form')
            return $(':input', this).clearForm();
        if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea' )
            this.value = '';
        else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
            this.checked = false;
        else if (tag == 'select')
            this.selectedIndex = -1;
        else if (tag == 'td' && $(this).hasClass('status')) {
            // if you want to remove everything, use this
            $(this).html('');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code (in your edit), and assuming you call the function by doing something like `$('#myForm').clearForm()` (where `myForm` is a form element), then its never going to process `td` elements. The code takes a form & then recurses onto that form's [`:input` elements](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) to clear them. Given that `td` is not an `input`, they won't be included in the clearing.

If that is how you're using it, you could customise it as follows to get it to clear your `td`s (within the form) as well:

```
$.fn.clearForm = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tag == 'form') {
            $('td.status', this).empty();
            return $(':input', this).clearForm();
        }
        if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea' )
            this.value = '';
        else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
            this.checked = false;
        else if (tag == 'select')
            this.selectedIndex = -1;
    });
};
```

Comment: @Pandiya: how are you calling the plugin?

Comment: @pandiya - Oops, I obviously didn't read what I posted. That line was after a return statement. :)  Fixed now.

Comment: @Alconja ya i too didnt seem that

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do:

```
$('td.status').empty();
```